# How to bypass Form Flow's "did you mean" when user gives exact string

Tags: c#, botframework, formflow

One of the fields in my form flow provides the options: "None", "1", "2", "3", "4", and "More than 5". When I choose option "3" it asks me "Did you mean "3" or "4"?"

[image]

Is there a way to bypass "did you mean" when the provided answer already has an exact match in the options?

Is my only option to change the wording/format of my options?

Comment: Please share the code. We do not know the logic put by you in the backend to show the text.

Comment: Great answer from Nicolas below. The easiest (least work/refactoring) way to avoid this behavior would be moving the "none" option to the last choice and have your numbers align with the order of the choices

Comment: @JasonSowers I did exactly that. NicolasR's answer covered everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short answer for FormFlow and Dialogs cases:

When you type "4" your Prompt has a doubt between the 4th value based on a 1-indexed list (so the value "3") and the value "4" which is a match in your options.

If you specify a dedicated "recognizer" for your field, you should avoid this problem (see doc [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.formflow.advanced.iprompt-1.recognizer?WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365&view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable))

Note: there is a similar problem when using PromptDialog.Choice in Dialog, not in FormFlow. Using boolean properties `recognizeChoices`, `recognizeNumbers` and `recognizeOrdinals` is helpful in that case.

### Long answer for Dialogs case:

You are facing a case where your values are also a number.

The prompts used to display the choices (which are `PromptDialog.Choice` items) have the capacity to analyse the value that you provide by several means:

- Recognize choices: the prompt will attempt to recognize the selected value using the choices themselves
- Recognize numbers: the prompt will attempt to recognize numbers in the users utterance as the index of the choice to return
- Recognize ordinals: the prompt will attempt to recognize ordinals like "the first one" or "the second one" as the index of the choice to return.

By default, all the recognizer are enabled. See their use in the framework [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/develop/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/PromptDialog.cs#L965)

Disabling "numbers" recognizers will fix your problem